# Timer recorded in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a registration form for users (Name , password, retype password, email) then insert them to MySQL, I did that but I'm stuck with how to record how long the user took to type in his password.

I am using PHP and HTML

Comment: you probably interested in onfocus and keypress keyboard events in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setInterval` to increment some number every second, starting the interval when the input gets focus, and clearing the interval when it loses focus.

```js
    var timeSpent = 0;
    var interval;
    document.getElementById('password2').addEventListener('focus', function() {
        interval = setInterval(function() { 
            timeSpent++;
            document.getElementById('timeSpent').value = timeSpent;
        }, 1000);
    });
    document.getElementById('password2').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
        if (interval && event.target.value === document.getElementById('password').value) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('password2').addEventListener('blur', function() {
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
```

```html
Password: <input id="password" type="password"/><br/>
Reenter Password: <input id="password2" type="password"/><br/>
Time Spend: <input id="timeSpent" type="number"/><br/>
```

Then in PHP you will have something like:

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, password_hash, time_spent)
VALUES(:name, :hash, :time)");

$statement->execute(array(
    "name" => $_POST['username'],
    "hash" => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
    "time" => $_POST['timeSpent']
));
```

Comment: how can i store Time Spend in my database ?